# PHP + AJAX - How To Pass $_GET Variables Into AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, get

I'm looking to make a database connection test with AJAX, I want the user to fill in their database information, and then have a test button that takes the $_GET variables filled out so far, process those $_GET variables in a database connection test script, and then return success or fail. My question is, how would I pass the $_GET variables filled out so far, without reloading the page?

Thanks for any help - Necro.

Comment: Yep, you're gonna use ajax like you said. Is there something specific you'd like us to help you with?

Comment: Your users need a lesson in security ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Sorry, I should be using POST, I know. When I was typing up the question I just typed GET. It was the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: @Necro I meant passing there server details to a 3rd party, without saying you would but there is nothing stopping you from storing. Also you should be wary of a curl script brute forcing, essentially your just creating a proxy open to abuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the ajax with either javascript or jquery

like with jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "serverside script to process on data",
    data:{name:youwant}, //name is a $_GET variable name here,
                           // and 'youwant' is its value to be passed 
    success: function(data){
         alert("return here if success")

    }
})
```

Comment: `name` is a `$_GET` variable name here, and 'youwant' is its value to be passed

Comment: `youwant` undefined variable though here. Put quotes around to be a string. (if that's what you intended)

Answer (score 1):

you can try jquery.ajax() - method like this..

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'server_script?para_name='+para_value,
  success: function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
     alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

OR you can use jquery-ajax method like

```
 $.get("script", { para_name:"para_value", para_name:"para_value"});
```

For more info visit..[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp)

Comment: i really appreciate your answer but pls dont suggest w3schools

Comment: Same as above, I appreciate the above answer, they both work, but the below explains it to me much better.

Comment: @NullPointer : ok you can visit jquery official site :)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/